# How would you write a new word with stress on a syllable in dialogue?

Tags: hyphenation, italics

I am not able to find the answer to this by googling.

I am writing dialogue for a fiction story.

I have a few new words I have made up and want to stress a certain syllable in them.

For example:

> "I think juice-tice needs to happen in this case," she said.

Would I write it as above or as

> "I think *juice*-tice needs to happen in this case," she said.

Or

> "I think *juice*tice needs to happen in this case," she said.

I do want to stress the *juice*.

Comment: I think italics would do it but I would lose the hyphen. I see no other way in English in a story or novel.

Comment: The previous sentences would already set up the wordplay from justice to the juice issue, so you don't need to hit the reader too hard on the switcheroo.

Comment: Putting it all in capitals is possible (JUICE-tice), but more in a comic or email than in a literary novel.